# Replace web.config element for Octopus Deploy

Tags: web-config, continuous-integration, octopus-deploy, deploying, autodeploy

This is part of Web.config

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1001/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_I" contract="API.I" name="BasicHttpBinding_IStore" />
```

I wan't to change address="http://localhost:1001/" to address="http://10.133.1.5:1001/" or any when deploy with Octopus.
I read Document but don't understand, anyone can help my issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can either do a web.config xml transform within the project and use the XML transform feature within Octopus: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files

Or you can use Octopus variables and replace variables in files within Octopus: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Substitute+Variables+in+Files